# How can I find out what <Leader> is set to? And is it possible to remap <Leader>?

Tags: key-bindings

How can I figure out which key is set as my `<Leader>`, and how do I remap it?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

By default your `<leader>` is `\`, backslash. You can check it with:

```
:echo mapleader
```

If this gives you an `E121: Undefined variable: mapleader`, it means it's set to the default of `\`. If it gives you something else, then it's that :-)

You can easily remap it. I mapped it to the space-bar:

```
:let mapleader = "\<Space>"
```

Note that the value of `mapleader` is used at the moment the mapping is defined. So this example:

```
let mapleader = ","
nnoremap <Leader>a :echo "Hey there ,"<CR>

let mapleader = "\<Space>"
nnoremap <Leader>a :echo "Hey there space"<CR>
```

Will produce *two* mappings: `,a` and `<Space>a`.

This means that the *current* value of `mapleader` is not necessarily the value that was used to define your mappings!

In addition, there's the `maplocalleader`, which is the same as `mapleader`, except that it's used by `<LocalLeader>` and that it's local to the current buffer.

More information about `<Leader>` can be found in Vim's help with [`:help mapleader`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#mapleader).

Comment: Why do we need a backslash in `"\<Space>"`?

Comment: The backslash is required because otherwise vim will recognize "<Space>" as a normal string and not the code for the space key. See `:help expr-string` for examples.

Comment: Just a note: e.g. `let mapleader = ' '` also works for setting `<Leader>` to space. If there are any possible side-effects by using this syntax, feel free to mention them.

Comment: It appears that `maplocalleader` is also set to backslash by default.  Maybe that's what was meant by "is the same as `mapleader`, but I wasn't sure at first.

Comment: How can I undo a `let mapleader = ","` after the fact? I tried `unlet mapleader` as well as `let mapleader = "\"` but it doesn't work.
I need this because I am using this bundle https://github.com/amix/vimrc where it suggests to have my own separate configuration file. The bundle maps leader to the comma so I want to undo this in my separate config file.

Comment: I also need to unmap my leader. I accidentally saved it to let mapleader = ";" and now I don't want that mapping anymore

Answer (score 11):

You can display the current leader key like this `:let mapleader`

Comment: Trying this, I get `E121: Undefined variable: mapleader`.

Comment: Then for some reason the mapleader was not set or has been unset

Comment: Oh, got it. Just a note for others then, if you don't *explicitly* set the leader key then you get the error above.

Comment: if you get `E121: Undefined variable: mapleader`, that means it was not set, which will use the default, which is a backslash `"\"`