# Can Escape be disabled in insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, escape, habit-breaking

I'm trying to retrain my fingers to refrain from using <kbd>Escape</kbd> so often.

Can I disable <kbd>Escape</kbd> when I'm in insert mode, leaving just <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as the only ways to return to normal mode?

I've tried `:inoremap <Esc> <nop>` but that seems to half-break both <kbd>Escape</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.

Comment: Do you mean "leaving just Control+[" rather than "leaving just Escape+["?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that's possible, the problem is that `<Esc>` is the same as `<C-[>` as in the key codes that vim receives when you type it is exactly the same.

You can reproduce this and validate it in insert mode by hitting `<C-v>` first and then `<Esc>` and `<C-[>` respectively and you'll see it sends the same key code to vim.

Hence VIM cannot distinguish between the two (at least within a terminal), I am not too sure if things are different for gui versions.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Linux (though not an exact answer), I recommend that you map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then use [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) to adjust <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> behavior as follows:

- when pressed by itself, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> behaves like <kbd>Esc</kbd>;
- when combined with another key, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> behaves like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

So you can press both <kbd>Esc</kbd> and a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> combination more easily than any other solution.

To remap the keys, try this command in Linux:

```
setxkbmap -option '' -option 'ctrl:nocaps'
```

It resets already existing options first and then set <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as an additional <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. I know, weird name. If you don't want to reset options first, omit `-option ''`. It may be useful if you have other options set in another place.

There are other options related to <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

```
$ grep escape /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
800:  caps:swapescape      Swap ESC and Caps Lock
801:  caps:escape          Make Caps Lock an additional ESC
```

[`xcape`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xcape.1) allows you to use a modifier key as another key when pressed and released on its own.

This is my `.xinitrc`:

```
... snip ...
setxkbmap -option '' -option 'ctrl:nocaps'
pkill xcape
xcape
exec xmonad
```

Comment: I would suggest "s/recommand/recommend/", "s/already exist options/already existing options/", "s/then set capslock as additional ctrl/then sets capslock as an additional ctrl/", "s/may useful in case of you have/may be useful in case you have/", "s/is other options relate/are other options related to/". Apologies for not doing it myself, but don't have the rep yet

Comment: This is a nice workaround, but I've already remapped [CapsLock] to be my [Control]...

Comment: muru, jalanb Thanks for correct my terrible writing.

Comment: @alxndr This method could make [CapsLock] as both [Control] and [Escape]

Comment: Interesting idea. On OS X it looks like this is achievable by combining the Karabiner (formerly known as KeyRemap4MacBook) and Seil utilities from Takayama Fumihiko on pqrs.org.

Comment: @alxndr Yup. It works great! There's a full set of instructions here: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/

Comment: Actually, `setxkbmap` is not Linux, but X11. So you have it on your Solaris or FreeBSD box as well, but not on your Linux framebuffer device without X11.

Answer (score 5):

In insert mode, you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>. You will see the literal interpretation of those key sequences according to vim. (See `:h i_CTRL_V`)

Most importantly, you'll notice that they are the same (at least for me in both vim in xterm and gvim). So you cannot disable one and not the other.

In general, I'd say it's a bad idea to remap <kbd>Esc</kbd>, as you'll have unintended consequences.

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed the backslash. Disable <kbd>Esc</kbd> like this:

```
:inoremap \<Esc> Nop
```

From comment of [user](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/20/tokoyami) under [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/282/153) answer:

> The backslash is required because otherwise vim will recognize < Space> as a  normal string and not the code for the space key. See :help expr-string for examples.

Comment: This doesn't really apply for `map`. The '\' is used to escape key codes when using `normal` via `execute` calls. Very confusing imho. Example from the `execute` help: `:execute "normal ixxx\<Esc>"`. The use in `mapleader` is probably related to that. Or it just accepts `expr-string`s.