# What is <Leader>?

Tags: key-bindings, terminology

I see `<Leader>` quite often in other people's vimrc files.
[Like this one.](http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.html)

What is it? 
What does it do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find out what <Leader> is set to?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/281/how-can-i-find-out-what-leader-is-set-to)

Comment: Akshay: Not a duplicate, that wants to check the value of `<leader>`, this one wants to know what `<leader>` means. So that that value can be interpreted. It is the difference between asking "In newton motion what is v?" and "Given an apple falled from a 10m high tree, what is v when it hits the ground?'

Comment: So, there is no difference between `<Leader>` and `<leader>`, right?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Vim is full of various commands, which are assigned to almost all keys on the keyboard. But this causes a problem: Which commands can we use for our own commands, without interfering with existing ones? And at this moment, the `<Leader>` key comes into play. Think about `<Leader>`-key like a namespace for any user-defined commands. You can assign any command to a mapping with a leading `<Leader>` and you can be fully confident that your mapping won't break anything.

Default key for `<Leader>` is backslash.

Answer (score 15):

To quote [`:help <Leader>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#mapleader):

> To define a mapping which uses the "mapleader" variable, the special string
>   "`<Leader>`" can be used.  It is replaced with the string value of "mapleader".
>   If "mapleader" is not set or empty, a backslash is used instead.  Example:
>
> ```
>    :map <Leader>A  oanother line<Esc>
> ```
>
> Works like:
>
> ```
>    :map \A  oanother line<Esc>
> ```
>
> But after:
>
> ```
>    :let mapleader = ","
> ```
>
> It works like:
>
> ```
>    :map ,A  oanother line<Esc>
> ```

In other words, it lets the first key of mappings (specified in terms of `<Leader>`) be user defined.

Comment: I believe that the rationale behind the `<Leader>` is that it provides you with a "clean" way to provide custom shortcuts, without overriding existing Vim shortcuts.