# "Put" command in normal mode: Insert a new line after "put"

Tags: key-bindings

The easiest way to explain this question is to show you my code and what I am trying to do.

Here is some code, before any edits are made:

```
// some block of code here
// blaa blaa
// please imagine these comments are code

// another block of code after some whitespace break between
// this block and the previous
// blaa blaa
// please imagine these comments are code
```

Now imagine I want to edit "in-between" the 2 blocks of code above. I enter insert mode when the caret is between the blocks (on the whitespace line) I add some lines of whitespace (an extra 2), go up a line and enter a new variable name.

```
// some block of code here
// blaa blaa
// please imagine these comments are code

double a_very_long_variable_name = 0.0;

// another block of code after some whitespace break between
// this block and the previous
// blaa blaa
// please imagine these comments are code
```

Now I escape from insert mode (back to normal mode) and yank the variable name "a_very_long_variable_name" using "yiw" (yank in word) command.

I go down 1 line, to the blank line and press "p" to put. I get this.

```
// some block of code here
// blaa blaa
// please imagine these comments are code

double a_very_long_variable_name = 0.0;
a_very_long_variable_name
// another block of code after some whitespace break between
// this block and the previous
// blaa blaa
// please imagine these comments are code
```

What I want is to "put", but to add a new whitespace line (a newline character) after the put command.

- Is there already a command to do this? It seems like something that would be frequently required.

I believe I can accomplish this by creating a new command like this in my vimrc. (I am not sure yet what the nmap syntax is... Will search for this now.)

```
nmap <S-p> p$i<Enter><Esc>
```

Edit: The command above should actually be:

```
nnoremap <S-p> p$a<CR><Esc>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed a single command that will do this:

```
:put
```

This can be abbreviated to `:pu`.

You can also add a `!`  to insert the new line of text above the cursor:

```
:put!
```

Or add a `[line]` to insert the text after/before any line you specify in the buffer:

```
:4put
:4put!
```

See `:help :put` for more details.

If you wanted to map it, you could write:

```
:nnoremap <S-P> :put<CR>
```

Although, personally, I'd use a different trigger: `P` in normal mode is a command I use all the time.

Comment: If you use [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired), `]p` will be forced to be line-wise which will have a similar behavior to `:put`. Unimpaired also has `[<space>` / `]<space>` mappings which make adding whitespace more pleasant.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `o` in normal mode see [`:h o`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#o):

> Begin a new line below the cursor and insert text, repeat [count] times.

Note there is also `O` which adds a newline above the cursor.

For example you may want a mapping like this:

```
nnoremap <S-p> po<Esc>
```

As a side note I use these mappings to insert a newline without leaving normal mode:

```
" Quickly insert an empty new line without entering insert mode
nnoremap <Leader>o o<Esc>0"_D
nnoremap <Leader>O O<Esc>0"_D
```

The `0"_D` delete the content of the new line using the black hole register to avoid having a newline containing some whitespaces.

---

Also it is not part of your question but your mapping can be `nnoremap P` instead of `nnoremap <S-p>`

Comment: Is there a reason to use po<ESC> rather than o<ESC>p ?

Comment: @user3728501 Well it depends on what you want to do. Your mapping `p$a<CR><Esc>` put your yanked text and add a new line under this text. `po<Esc>`does the same while `o<Esc>p` will add a newline and then put the yanked text on it.

Comment: Ah ok, but the result is always the same?

Comment: @user3728501 No `po<Esc>` will give you `yanked text[newline]` while `o<Esc>p` will give you `[newline]yanked text` I think you will understand it better if you test it by yourself: create a buffer with two lines containing `1` and `2` respectively, yank something and then put your cursor on the `1` and try both of the mappings you should see the difference pretty easily.

Comment: Ah - yes I can see the difference now thanks.

Comment: `po<ESC>` is the one I want I think because it more closely resembles how `p` works? `P` should be `o<ESC>p` ?

Comment: @user3728501 Once again it all depends on what you like better. Personally I wouldn't do a mapping for that I would simply use "vanilla" `p` or `P` and use my `<leader>o` and `<leader>O` mappings but it is only my personal preference :)

Comment: What is <leader> / what does <leader>o do?

Comment: @user3728501 see [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/836/1841) you could replace `<leader>o` by whatever key you want to map.