# What does [count]<leader> mean?

Tags: key-bindings, count, plugin-nerdcommenter, leader

I found a command in NERDCommenter like this:

```
[count]<leader>cc |NERDComComment|
```

I have installed the plugin. But, I don't know how to make it work. So what's the meaning of that command? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 13):

- `[count]` is optional. If given, the mapping works for *count* lines (ie. comments out *count* lines).
- `<Leader>` is usually the backslash key (`\`), although this can be remapped (also see [What is <Leader>?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/836/51) and [How can I find out what <Leader> is set to? And is it possible to remap &ltLeader>?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/281/51))
- `cc` is exactly that: two `c`'s.
- `NERDComComment` has nothing to do with this key mapping, it's the help tag for more information.

So, if you want to comment out the current line: use `\cc` from normal mode. For the current and next line, use `2\cc`, etc.
You you can select lines with visual mode and then press `\cc` to comment out all the selected lines.

Answer (score 2):

The command is used in normal mode by typing first a count, like `10`, followed by the `<Leader>` key (default is `\`) and finally `cc`.

Example; type `10\cc` in normal mode to comment out 10 lines starting at the cursor position. Omit the count to only comment out the current line.

Many people like to remap the `<Leader>` key to `,`. More info here: http://usevim.com/2012/07/20/vim101-leader/