# How can I work with splits in Vim without Ctrl-W?

Tags: key-bindings, vim-windows, split

My terminal doesn't allow me to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, because that's a shortcut for closing a terminal tab.

I like working with splits, but I can't find any way to do so without using `C-W`. This forced me to use tabs, because I can switch between them with `gt`, `gT` or `#gt` where # is a number, but I find this less convenient than splits as I can only see the contents of one file at a time.

I can't use `mouse=a` either since my terminal doesn't support that.

How can I work with splits in Vim without the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> combo available?

Comment: Use mappings to `wincmd`

For example you can map:

`:nmap wj :wincmd j<cr>` it's acts same as `CTRL-W j` (move to window below).

`:help wincmd`

Comment: @AlexKroll Why don't you post that as an answer? :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It's not full cover for this problem I think. `CTRL-W j` works with counters (go to n-th window below from current) my solution does not.

Comment: I don't normally appreciate advice like this, but I would look for another terminal. `<C-W>` is too useful a shortcut (not only in many places in Vim, but also in bash) to forfeit. I'd be curious what other key bindings are consumed by the terminal -- `<C-T>`? At the very least, I'd look into whether these are configurable in the terminal.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can remap `<C-w>` to another combination, for example:

```
:nnoremap <C-e> <C-w>
```

You can now use `<C-e>` and it will act as if you've pressed `<C-w>`.

This will overwrite the default `<C-e>` mapping (scroll down). Vim already uses every key on the keyboard, and the only way to prevent this is using the leader key, which acts like a "prefix":

```
:nnoremap <Leader>w <C-w>
```

Unless you've remapped `<Leader>`, you can now use `\w` (after each other). I actually prefer this since I don't like CTRL+key combinations.

See [What is <Leader>?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/836/51) and
[How can I find out what <Leader> is set to? And is it possible to remap <Leader>?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/281/51).

You don't *need* to use the `<leader>` key, you can use anything as a prefix, for example `;` works just as well:

```
:nnoremap ; <C-w>
```

And now `;w`, `;s`, etc. will work.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 26):

I actually use `:wincmd` more often than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> because I find it easier to type the abbreviated `:winc`.

For example, the equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> is `:winc l`.

Answer (score 13):

I have set up the following remaps in my `.vimrc`:

```
nmap <C-h> <C-w>h
nmap <C-j> <C-w>j
nmap <C-k> <C-w>k
nmap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

Now I can use `Ctrl+h` to move to the left window, `Ctrl+l` to move to the right window, etc. It just seems to logically fit with the normal navigation of Vim.

Comment: Note that mapping Ctrl+h in a terminal doesn't always work, as this is often the backspace key. See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/disable-esc-but-keep-c/3570#3570) and [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3119/51).

Comment: Also, you may use `nnoremap <cr> <c-w>w`, since the return key is not used much in normal mode. Then it is effortless to cycle through the splits.

Comment: I use: mj mh mk ml ...

Comment: mapping c-k in terminal is awful... c-j as well. It doesn't work as planned.

Answer (score 7):

To deal with splits I use the [submode-plugin](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode.git) which is actually pretty convenient: It allows you to create a new mode ("mode" like in normal mode, visual mode, insert mode, etc...) where you define new key bindings.

With that you don't have to use <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd> anymore and as you are in a new mode all the keys are free to bind: no more problems like "Damn I can't find a key combination which as a signification and isn't mapped yet"

You can install the plugin with any regular plugin manager, and here are some of my configuration to give you some inspiration:

---

I created a new mode that I called `WindowsMode` in which I manipulate my splits:

```
call submode#enter_with('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<Leader>k', ':echo "windows mode"<CR>')
call submode#leave_with('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<Leader>')
```

These lines means that I enter in the mode with <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> and I exit the mode with <kbd>Leader</kbd>: After I hit <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> all the keys I hit will:

- Do nothing if I didn't defined a mapping for them in this mode
- Do what I decided to map them in this mode (see the rest of the answer)
- Go back to normal mode if I hit <kbd>Leader</kbd>

---

Once I'm in `WindowsMode` these lines make <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> navigate through the splits like <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>hjkl</kbd>

```
" Change of windows with hjkl
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'j', '<C-w>j')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'k', '<C-w>k')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'h', '<C-w>h')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'l', '<C-w>l')
```

---

I used these lines to split the windows with <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>!</kbd>:

```
" split windows with / and !
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '/', '<C-w>s')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '!', '<C-w>v')
```

And <kbd>q</kbd> close a split:

```
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'q', '<C-w>c')
```

---

Move the splits with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>hjkl</kbd>:

```
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<C-j>', '<C-w>J')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<C-k>', '<C-w>K')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<C-h>', '<C-w>H')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<C-l>', '<C-w>L')
```

---

Vim-submode allows to do a lot of powerful things, see [the doc](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode/blob/master/doc/submode.txt) for more details.

---

**EDIT** Another approach of the Window submode is described [here](http://ddrscott.github.io/blog/2016/making-a-window-submode/). I think the method used by the author is even closer to answer the question: Here is used to create a new mode but all the `<c-w>something` mappings are available with the same keys in the submode:

```
" Go through every letter
for key in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
\           'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
  " maps lowercase, uppercase and <C-key>
  call submode#map('window', 'n', '', key, '<C-w>' . key)
  call submode#map('window', 'n', '', toupper(key), '<C-w>' . toupper(key))
  call submode#map('window', 'n', '', '<C-' . key . '>', '<C-w>' . '<C-'.key . '>')
endfor

" Go through symbols. Sadly, '|', not supported in submode plugin.
for key in ['=','_','+','-','<','>']
  call submode#map('window', 'n', '', key, '<C-w>' . key)
endfor
```

This way all the mappings `<c-w>lowerCaseKey`, `<c-w>upperCaseKey`, `<c-w><c-Key>` and the mappings `<c-w>=_+-<>` are all accessible in the window mode without the prefix `<c-w>`