# Navigating between split vi windows

Tags: vimrc, microsoft-windows, split

On Windows OS, I am using Chrome web browser to ssh into a remote Linux terminal and using vi there. One can use `Ctrl-w + hjkl` to navigate among split vi windows. However, the problem is `Ctrl-w` instantly closes Chrome tab (Windows OS) before I can do anything with vi. How can I navigate between vi windows when I cannot use `Ctrl-w`?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/569248/879179) for a possible solution in Chrome itself, disabling the `Ctrl+W` behavior in Chrome, which should make it available in your SSH sessions.

Comment: I tried binding `Ctrl+w` to another extension, however the shortcut activates that extension instead of sending to remote terminal.

Comment: Map something else to Ctrl-w? Say, `nnoremap <leader>w <c-w>`? Or use [`:wincmd`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Awincmd)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comment of [muru](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/205/muru).

Solved the problem using https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3729/33095

> `:nnoremap <Leader>w <C-w>`
>
> Unless you've remapped , you can now use \w (after each other). I actually prefer this since I don't like CTRL+key combinations.

and/or using https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3737/33095.

> I actually use `:wincmd` more often than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> because I find it easier to type the abbreviated `:winc`.